# ports getting opened when running spring boot app with reactive framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

app is running on free bsd 8.x and it is fairly simple internally uses netty-client to make rest calls using spring boot webclient library and the spring reactor framework. I'm pretty sure I disabled the server mode for spring boot app

when I run sockstat -l -L on the machine I see this output

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
    root     java       1074 807 udp46 *:*                   *:* 
    root     java       1074 811 udp46 *:*                   *:*
```

not able to figure out why app is listening on this port..! can someone pls help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS resolution uses UDP in order to resolve the addresses.
By default is listens on any local address, and the system picks up an ephemeral port. You can configure to an exact address following the code below:

```
HttpClient.create()
          .resolver(spec -> spec.bindAddressSupplier(() -> new InetSocketAddress(...)));
```

More information you can find [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/transport/NameResolverProvider.NameResolverSpec.html#bindAddressSupplier-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_host_name_resolution_2).